# Bind datepicker in hidden element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have some elements hidden by default and displayed on some button click by setting angular scope variables with ng-if. Now the problem is, datepicker is not working in these hidden elements even after visible.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class ='col-md-2 control-label'>Receipt Mode</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select ng-model="newItem.receipt_mode" required style="min-width:180px;">
            <option value="" ng-selected="">-Select-</option>
            <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
            <option value="Bank">Bank</option>
            <option value="Cheque">Cheque</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" ng-if="newItem.receipt_mode=='Cheque'">
    <label class ='col-md-2 control-label'>Cheque Date</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type='text' class='form-control datepicker' required ng-model='newItem.cheque_date' />
    </div>
</div>
```

The script,

```
app.controller('receiptVoucherController', function($scope) {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: "m/d/yy"});
});
```

It's working fine with default visible elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the angular documentation:

> ngIf completely removes and recreates the element in the DOM rather than changing its visibility via the display css property

What you can do is create a directive which that calls datepicker whenever it's added to the dom (link function will be called):

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDatePicker', function() {

    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element){
            $(element).datepicker({dateFormat: "m/d/yy"});
        }
    };
});
```

View:

```
<input my-date-picker' />
```